# Trying to fadein/fadeout html5 audio file vuejs / vanilla js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, html5-audio

**Goal:**

- Audio fades in and out on first play/pause toggle, need to have it toggling sound continually

**Issue**

- Second time toggle audio cuts and skips

HTML

```
<div class="music-player">
    <audio
      ref="audio"
      src="@/assets/audio/bg-music.ogg"
      preload
      loop
      id="audio"
      muted
    ></audio>
    <div @click="toggleSound()" class="toggle-sound"></div>
</div>
```

JS - **UPDATED**

```
methods: {
  toggleSound() {
    let backgroundAudio = this.$refs.audio;

    //Fade In
    if (
      !document.querySelector(".toggle-sound").classList.contains("paused")
    ) {
      console.log("fading in");
      let actualVolumeFadeIn = 0;
      document.querySelector(".toggle-sound").classList.add("paused");
      clearInterval(fadeInInterval);
      let fadeInInterval = setInterval(function() {
        actualVolumeFadeIn = (parseFloat(actualVolumeFadeIn) + 0.1).toFixed(
        1
      );
        if (actualVolumeFadeIn <= 1) {
          backgroundAudio.volume = actualVolumeFadeIn;
        } else {
          backgroundAudio.play();
        }
      }, 100);
      return false;
    }

    //Fade Out
    if (
      document.querySelector(".toggle-sound").classList.contains("paused")
    ) {
      console.log("fading out");
      let actualVolumeFadeOut = backgroundAudio.volume;
      clearInterval(fadeOutInterval);
      let fadeOutInterval = setInterval(function() {
      actualVolumeFadeOut = (parseFloat(actualVolumeFadeOut) - 0.1).toFixed(
        1
      );
        if (actualVolumeFadeOut >= 0) {
          backgroundAudio.volume = actualVolumeFadeOut;
        } else {
          document.querySelector(".toggle-sound").classList.remove("paused");
          backgroundAudio.pause();
        }
        }, 100);
        return false;
      }
    },
  }
```

Comment: I think you can't reference the interval for clearInterval inside the anonymous function declaration

Comment: So when it's "paused" you interval from 1 to 0 then set it unpaused  and when it's not paused you interval from 0 to 1 and set it paused ? Shouldn't it be the otherway around?

Comment: You should get the current volume from the audio element instead of using out of scope actualVolume in your code. It's outside the scope of the anonymous function you declare for the intervals.

Comment: Thanks mate for point those things out - I have updated my code with your feedback and fades in and out on the first toggle. Next problem I have is the second button toggle the audio is cutting/skipping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to get it working:

HTML

```
<audio
  ref="audio"
  src="@/assets/audio/bg-music.ogg"
  preload
  loop
  id="audio"
  muted
></audio>
<div
  @click="toggleSound()"
  class="toggle-sound"
  v-bind:class="this.state.backgroundAudioState"
></div>
```

JS

```
data: () => ({
  ...
  state: {
    backgroundAudioState: "paused",
  },
}),
methods: {
  toggleSound() {
    let backgroundAudio = this.$refs.audio;
    let actualVolumeFadeOut = backgroundAudio.volume;
    let actualVolumeFadeIn = 0;

    //Fade In
    if (this.state.backgroundAudioState === "paused") {
      console.log("fading in");
      this.state.backgroundAudioState = "playing";
      clearInterval(fadeInInterval);
      let fadeInInterval = setInterval(function() {
        actualVolumeFadeIn = (parseFloat(actualVolumeFadeIn) + 0.1).toFixed(1);
        if (actualVolumeFadeIn <= 1) {
          backgroundAudio.volume = actualVolumeFadeIn;
        } else {
          backgroundAudio.play();
        }
      }, 100);
      return false;
    }

    //Fade Out
    if (this.state.backgroundAudioState === "playing") {
      console.log("fading out");
      this.state.backgroundAudioState = "paused";
      
      let fadeOutInterval = setInterval(function() {
        actualVolumeFadeOut = (parseFloat(actualVolumeFadeOut) - 0.1).toFixed(1);
        if (actualVolumeFadeOut >= 0) {
          backgroundAudio.volume = actualVolumeFadeOut;
        } else {
          backgroundAudio.pause();
          clearInterval(fadeOutInterval);
        }
      }, 100);
      return false;
    }
  },
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Fading in and out are audio effects and should be implemented with an audio tool directly on the audio file. [ffmpeg](https://ffmpeg.org/) is very basic (and free). Scripting volume levels client side is full of challenges considering mobile devices especially. There are user interface issues. Automating volume (and even automatic start) will not work consistently across device types or browser types.